# oracle table_privileges values

Tags: oracle, privileges

[image]

Does anybody know the values that are given in the table_privileges? I already found out what "A" means. But I did not find out for what the "S" stands for. I think this isnt documented. It has something to do with update privileges on particular columns.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to use the `table_privileges` view?  It would be much more common to use the `dba_tab_privs` (or `all_tab_privs') and `role_tab_privs` to examine table-level privileges.  I believe `table_privileges` is somewhat specified in the SQL standard so perhaps you're trying to get some level of database independence but looking at the documentation for the `table_privileges` view in various databases, it doesn't appear that the set of columns is the same across database vendors so I'm not sure it buys you anything.

Comment: no i just stumbled across a statement using table_privileges. thank you for the advice ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing you are missing is that we can grant UPDATE on a subset of a table's columns.

First of all, let's just grant SELECT on a table.  The value of UPDATE_PRIV is 'N', for *None*:

```
SQL> grant select on t23 to mr_x;

Grant succeeded.


SQL> select select_priv, update_priv 
  2  from table_privileges
  3  where table_name = 'T23'
  4  /

S U
- -
Y N

SQL>
```

Now, if I grant UPDATE on a single column  the value of UPDATE_PRIV is 'S', presumably for *Some*:

```
SQL> grant update (col2) on t23 to mr_x
  2  /

Grant succeeded.

SQL> select select_priv, update_priv 
  2  from table_privileges
  3  where table_name = 'T23'
  4  /

S U
- -
Y S

SQL>
```

Finally, I grant UPDATE on the whole table the value of UPDATE_PRIV is 'A', for *All*:

```
SQL> grant update  on t23 to mr_x
  2  /

Grant succeeded.

SQL> select select_priv, update_priv 
  2  from table_privileges
  3  where table_name = 'T23'
  4  /

S U
- -
Y A

SQL>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry but having noticed [an answer](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=316752) that @JustinCave gave to this very question back in 2005 I have to post it.

> From the SQL Reference documentation on table_privileges
>
> http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch2486.htm#1318903
>
> "TABLE_PRIVILEGES contains information on grants on objects for which
>   the user is the grantor, grantee, or owner, or PUBLIC is the grantee.
>   This view is included for compatibility with Oracle version 6. Oracle
>   Corporation recommends that you do not use this view."
>
> Given that Oracle recommends you not use this view, I would strongly
>   suggest that you use the DBA_TAB_PRIVS view instead. The information
>   there should be a bit easier to decipher.

Comment: Nice find.  At least Justin in 2012 is consistent with his younger self!

Comment: @Ben - Too bad the younger self appeared to have better Google Fu.  I tried to find a reference to `TABLE_PRIVILEGES` in the documentation earlier today and was not nearly as successful as I was 7 years ago.

Comment: @JustinCave, your Google Fu may be waning but apparently my date Fu is having far more problems. I've edited this answer as, as you pointed out your original post was 6 years later than I originally stated... doh!